# SyntaxError using override_settings in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to configurate a unittest for a Django application.
Needed to set some values as the database so I thought I could use a override_settings function. When I run this code I get the following error.

Code:

```
from zope.interface import implements
from twisted.python import failure, log
from twisted.cred import portal, checkers, error, credentials
from twisted.internet import defer

from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings 
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password

@override_settings(DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'})
class DjangoAuthChecker:
    implements(checkers.ICredentialsChecker)
    credentialInterfaces = (credentials.IUsernamePassword,
    credentials.IUsernameHashedPassword)

    def _passwordMatch(self, matched, user):
        if matched:
            return user
        else:
            return failure.Failure(error.UnauthorizedLogin())

    def requestAvatarId(self, credentials, connection):

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=credentials.username)
            return defer.maybeDeferred(
                check_password,
                credentials.password,
                user.password).addCallback(self._passwordMatch, user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return defer.fail(error.UnauthorizedLogin())
```

Could you tell me what's wrong? I also need some good advice on hand for tests in Django.

Error:

```
(.venv_test)sgongar@debian8-64bits-dev:~/Dev/client/protocol/tests$ python test_creds.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_creds.py", line 48, in <module>
    from ampauth.testing import DjangoAuthChecker
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/client/protocol/ampauth/testing.py", line 36
    @override_settings(DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'})
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the whole dictionary such as

```
@override_settings(DATABASES = {'default':{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}})
```

or you can use override settings as a context manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! ;)

Comment: Careful. We found this function not to work reliably in production. Fields randomly become missing!